# Include whole directory of scripts using Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Is it possible to include a whole directory of scripts with Jade? My current scripts.jade file looks like this:

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/angular.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/angular-resource.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/angular-route.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/core.js")
```

I was hoping from something like this:

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/*.js")
```

or this:

```
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "/vendor/*.js" -->
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no possibility to use such wildcards in Jade, it has no such notion of your filesystem.

**You can create a mixin** that will help a bit though, for example:

```
mixin scripts(path, names)
  - each name in names
      script(type="text/javascript", src=path+name+".js")

+scripts("/vendor/", ["angular", "angular-resource", "angular-route"])
```

For the possibility of automatical scripts injection into a html/jade/etc. code, you should use a build system, e.g. **gulp with a gulp-inject plugin** https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject

Comment: Splendid, gulp-inject should work nicely. It's to switch between unminified and minified script references in the index page on this small boilerplate project iv'e created: https://github.com/andybriggs/spa-boilerplate